# Setting up Shopware 6 fails with PHP XML error

Tags: php, apache2, mariadb, php7

Currently setting up Shopware 6 Community Edition ( https://www.shopware.com/de/download/ ) on my Ubuntu machine.

I followed these steps: https://docs.shopware.com/de/shopware-6-de/erste-schritte/shopware-6-installieren

I also have all the requirements: https://docs.shopware.com/de/shopware-6-de/erste-schritte/systemvoraussetzungen

My machine:

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- PHP 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
- Apache 2.4.29

I created the apache2 configuration and followed the setup, including the setup of the database. Everything went fine. But when I try to access the page [myshopdomain.tld]/admin I only receive a blank page with a 500 internal server error in the developer console, showing the GET requests (it's not logged like a javascript debug message).
When looking in the error log, configured in the apache2 configuration, I see the following:

```
[authz_core:debug] [pid 10073] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug] [pid 10073] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[authz_core:debug] [pid 10073] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug] [pid 10073] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: DOMDocument::$documentElement in /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 615
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP Stack trace:
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP   1. {main}() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/public/index.php:0
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP   2. Shopware\\Production\\Kernel->boot() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/public/index.php:66
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP   3. Shopware\\Production\\Kernel->initializeContainer() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php:125
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP   4. Shopware\\Production\\Kernel->buildContainer() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:549
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP   5. Shopware\\Production\\Kernel->prepareContainer() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:656
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP   6. Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Framework->build() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:684
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP   7. Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Loader\\XmlFileLoader->load() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Framework.php:47
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP   8. Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Loader\\XmlFileLoader->parseFileToDOM() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php:46
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP   9. Symfony\\Component\\Config\\Util\\XmlUtils::loadFile() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php:411
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP  10. Symfony\\Component\\Config\\Util\\XmlUtils::parse() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/config/Util/XmlUtils.php:131
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP  11. Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Loader\\XmlFileLoader->validateSchema() /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/config/Util/XmlUtils.php:83
[php7:notice] [pid 10073] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAttributeNS() on null in /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php:615\nStack trace:\n#0 /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/config/Util/XmlUtils.php(83): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Loader\\XmlFileLoader->validateSchema(Object(DOMDocument), false)\n#1 /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/config/Util/XmlUtils.php(131): Symfony\\Component\\Config\\Util\\XmlUtils::parse('<?xml version="...', Array)\n#2 /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(411): Symfony\\Component\\Config\\Util\\XmlUtils::loadFile('/path/to/my/webroot...', Array)\n#3 /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(46): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Loader\\XmlFileLoader->parseFileToDOM('/path/to/my/webroot...')\n#4 /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/shopware/core in /path/to/my/webroot/htdocs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 615
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the PHP XML extension, on your distribution named [`php7.2-xml`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php7.2-xml). If that doesn't solve the problem, you will almost certainly need help from the Shopware developers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I said, I meet the requirements, including all the php extensions, including the php-xml extension. I also tried to install the php7.2-xml extension through apt-get, which said, that the extension is already installed.

Comment: @MarvinKlar Go, then, to: you will almost certainly need help from the Shopware developers.